# On what plane is 7292 Propellor Adventures based?

Tags: sets, vehicle, model-identification

The set [7292](https://brickset.com/sets/7292-1/Propeller-Adventures), *Propeller Adventures*, features a twin engine airplane. It looks a bit like the [de Havilland Mosquito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Mosquito), but not quite.

On what plane, if any, is it based?

[image: 7292 Propeller Adventures]

Comment: Related: [Help Identifying a LEGO plane](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9441/65)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a pretty generic twin engin-ed WWII bomber.  Maybe like this Mosquito bomber?

[image]

Comment: I have always made the connection to the Mosquito.